# Python Tkinter Button Box

Tags: python, button, tkinter, box

I have crated a button box in tkinter using this:

```
v = StringVar()
v.set("L")

b1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="1", variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0, bg="red")
```

The button is red BUT as I click on it it turns white.
How can I fix is?
I want it to be red all the time.
Thank You :)

Comment: Set the `activebackground` option to the same value as `bg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution: `selectcolor='red'`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a attribute activebackground

```
v = StringVar()
v.set("L")

b1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="1", variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0, bg="red",activebackground="red")
```

I think this will work